# R Studio query definition

Tags: rstudio

R Studio Query define

Using rstudio and making a decision tree using the C5.0 algorithm.
What  does `train.indices <- sample(1:nrow(iris), 100)` do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just choosing a random sample of 100 indices to be used for the training set, chosen from the number of indices available in your dataset. You could then get your training data using `iris.train <- iris[train.indices, ]`.

Comment: That's code for "the sequence from 1 to the number of rows in iris". The `nrow()` function counts the number of rows in the array/matrix used as an argument (in this case, the `iris` dataset). Writing like this is helpful since you don't need to know how many rows the `iris` dataset has in order to sample from the total number of available indices.